# Does anyone knows a web application security scanner for mac?

Tags: php, macos

Does anyone knows a web application security scanner for mac and easy to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly, yes: [Websecurify.app](http://www.websecurify.com/)

Another, command line only, from Google: [Skipfish](http://blog.sucuri.net/2010/03/closer-look-at-skipfish.html)

Comment: WOW, thank you so much, seems that is build for people like me. Apart of this one, do you know any good one you recommend on using?

Comment: Well, Google has got one, too: Skipfish – http://blog.sucuri.net/2010/03/closer-look-at-skipfish.html